# What material for DLP/SLA 3D printer bottom window?

Tags: materials, 3d-printing

What material is used for the bottom window of 3D printer that the cured resin layer does not stick to and that it is transparent to the uv (365 nm) light?
And what material is used for the top plate where the model should stick.

Comment: I would bet that the transparent window is made of [UV grade fused silica](http://www.newport.com/Optical-Materials/144943/1033/content.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. That will deal with UV light but how to prevent it from sticking to the cured resin?

Comment: Maybe some spray if nothing else can be used easily?